# How do I Programmatically fire a DoubleClick event for a specific ListView Item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I'm trying to programmaticaly fire a `DoubleClick` event on a specific item of a Windows Forms `ListView`, but can't seem to find how to do it.

To further explain it, upon opening a form I need to fire a `DoubleClick` event on a `ListViewItem` that's on that form, to open the next form. I can't find where to indicate what row I'm interested in firing that event on.

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried already? Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: @nilsK 
I don't understand what's so wrong with my question. I'm trying to do exactly what I've described but can't find how to approach the problem. The only slightly similar question on the site doesn't really give an answer how to do it.

Comment: You didn't provided any example code. `I don't know how to do it` questions are off-topic. What triggers your doubleclick? An example snippet for that would help to provide an answer. Are you unit-testing? Why do you want to do this? Please describe your problem, maybe there is a better / smarter way to solve it.

Comment: Look up x-y-problem!

Comment: You ca handle the ListView_DoubleClicked Event and check which row is selected. Based on the values of the selected item you can choose to show or not show a specific form. That being said: there are many questions on this website which can help you with this.

Comment: I have to agree with the above comments. Its not exact clear what your problem is. Do you need to execute the same code as if you where doublecllcking on a row but without the doubleclick ? That would not be hard to do so we think you might have another problem.

Comment: Never mind. I managed to find how to do it. It was much easier than I thought, by setting the SelectedItem before firing the DoubleClick event. but since I couldn't find anything similar, I thought it was much more complicated.

You know, something that might seem obvious to one, can sometimes elude another, so less judgmental remarks and more helpful ones really goes a long way. Just saying.

Comment: While the question seems to be (and probably is) [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but IMO it's steel a valid question. 

With the same reason which some one likes [`PerformClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(v=vs.110).aspx) method of a `Button` someone may like to have a `Activate` method for an `Item` to activate the item programattically. It's also useful for test purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know why you Need this, but on this way you can fire the doubleclick programmaticaly:

```
//I dont know when u will fire this Event so we create a Dump to call our Method
MouseEventArgs f;        

//call the Method
Test_DoubleClicked(sender,e);

private void Test_DoubleClicked(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // some code
}
```

Comment: Better would be to call a private method inside the `Test_DoubleClicked`event, and than just call that private method

Comment: Can you explain further? Where exactly is your doubleclick event fireing? Also, be aware, that calling the "callback" method for the doubleclick event is not the same as fireing the doubleclick event.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out what I was missing. The Listview's selected item needs to be set before firing the event.

Comment: While the solution has solve your problem, but it's better to put the logic in a method like `DoSomething(ListViewItem item){/**/}`. Then you can reuse the same logic in `ItemActivate` by calling `DoSomething(listView1.SelectedItems[0])`. Also in case that in some other part of your code you want to use the same logic along with setting an item as selected, it's enough to set `item.Selected = true;` and then `DoSomething(item)`. As you can see, setting selected item is not responsibility of `DoSomething`.

Comment: Also in general it's better to handle [`ItemActivate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemactivate(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than relying on double click. `ItemActivate` will raise on a double click as well.

Answer (score 0):

While the question seems to be (and in fact it is) [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but IMO it's steel a valid question.

With the same reason which some one likes [`PerformClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(v=vs.110).aspx) method of a `Button` someone may like to have a `Activate` method for an `Item` to activate the item programattically. It's also useful for test purpose.

**Right solution for most cases**

Before jumping to `Activate` method, as a comment on the OP's answer, I should say, while the solution which you shared has solved your problem, but here is the right solution for most cases:

It's better to put the logic in a method like `DoSomething(ListViewItem item){/**/}`. Then you can reuse the same logic in `ItemActivate` by calling `DoSomething(listView1.SelectedItems[0])`. Also in case that in some other part of your code you want to use the same logic along with setting an item as selected, it's enough to set item.Selected = true; and then `DoSomething(item)`.*

As you can see, setting selected item is not responsibility of `DoSomething`, and also in general it's better to handle `ItemActivate` rather than relying on  double click. `ItemActivate` will raise on a double click as well.

**Activating an Item Programmatically**

Here in this post I'll share an extension method for `ListViewItem` to perform item activation programmatically using a method called `Activate`, then to activate an `Item`, it's enough to call `item.Activate()` method.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public static class ListViewItemExtensions
{
    public static void Activate(this ListViewItem item)
    {
        if (item.ListView == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        var onItemActivate = item.ListView.GetType().GetMethod("OnItemActivate",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        item.Selected = true;
        onItemActivate.Invoke(item.ListView, new object[] { EventArgs.Empty });
    }
}
```